# Java - Better idiom for my control flow

Tags: java

I'd like to call a method that either returns false, or an integer. At the moment my code is:

```
int winningID = -1;
if((ID = isThereAWinner()) != -1) {
    // use the winner's ID
} else {
    // there's no winner, do something else
}

private int isThereAWinner() {
    // if a winner is found
    return winnersID;
    // else
    return -1;
}
```

I don't like the `if((ID = isThereAWinner()) != -1)` bit as it doesn't read very well, but unlike C you can't represent booleans as integers in Java. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use something similar to Mat's answer:

```
class Result {
    public static Result withWinner(int winner) {
        return new Result(winner);
    }

    public static Result withoutWinner() {
        return new Result(NO_WINNER);
    }

    private static final int NO_WINNER = -1;

    private int winnerId;

    private Result(int id) {
        winnerId = id;
    }

    private int getWinnerId() {
        return winnerId;
    }

    private boolean hasWinner() {
        return winnerId != NO_WINNER;
    }
}
```

This class hides the implementation details of how you actually represent if there were no winner at all.

Then in your winner finding method:

```
private Result isThereAWinner() {
    // if a winner is found
    return Result.withWinner(winnersID);
    // else
    return Result.withoutWinner();
}
```

And in your calling method:

```
Result result = isThereAWinner();
if(result.hasWinner()) {
    int id = result.getWinnerId();
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

It may seem a little bit too complex, but this approach is more flexible if there would be other result options in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like the fact that lots more data could be stored in the Results class, like maybe the exact order of the finishers, that could then be used later on. And as you say, it could have lots more methods that make sense of the data. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

What about something like:

```
private int getWinnerId() {
  // return winner id or -1
}

private boolean isValidId(int id) {
  return id != -1; // or whatever
}
```

```
int winnerId = getWinnerId();
if (isValidId(winnerId)) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

This is all quite subjective of course, but you usually expect an `isFoo` method to provide only a yes/no "answer".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it reads much better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are trying to return two values at once.  The approach you have taken is the simplest for this.  If you want a more OO or design pattern approach I would use a listener pattern.

```
interface WinnerListener {
    void onWinner(Int winnerId);
    void noWinner();
}

checkWinner(new WinnerListener() {
    // handle either action
});

private void checkWinner(WinnerListener wl) {
    // if a winner is found
    wl.onWinner(winnersID);
    // else
    wl.noWinner();
}
```

This approach works well with complex events like multiple arguments and multiple varied events. e.g. You could have multiple winners, or other types of events.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe overkill for what I want, but very interesting. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not. To avoid errors caused by mistaking if(a == b) for if(a = b), Java removes the conversion between boolean type and number types. Maybe you can try exceptions instead, but I think exception is somewhat more troublesome. (My English is not quite good. I wonder if I've made it clear...)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may wish to consider exceptions to help you with your understanding of asthetics of coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use Integer instead of int and return null instead of -1. Look from this point: "I am returning not integer, but some object that represents winner identity. No winner - no instance"

Answer (score 0):

Joe another suggestion, this is constructed based on @Mat and @buc mentioned little while ago, again this is all subjective of course I'm not sure what the rest of your class/logic is. You could introduce an enum with different ResultStatuses if it makes sense within the context of your code/exmaple.

As Matt mentioned you would expect isValid method to return a boolean yes/no (some may also complain of readability)

```
public enum ResultStatus {
    WINNER, OTHER, UNLUCKY
}
```

This could be an overkill as well and depends on the rest of your logic (and if logic is expanding) but I thought I'll suggest nonetheless my two cents! So therefore in your public class (similar to @bloc suggested) you could have a method such as below that will return the status of the result checked.

```
public ResultStatus getResultStatus() {
    if (isWinner()) {
        return ResultStatus.WINNER;
    } else {
        return isOtherCheck() ? ResultStatus.OTHER : ResultStatus.UNLUCKY;
    }
}
```